# How to select database using Poco MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, poco-libraries

What is the preferred way in Poco to issue the equivalent of the SQL `USE mychosendb` command via the MySQL data connector?

The [introductory example](https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html) to using Poco Data libraries indicates that the database one selects for use is a property/parameter of the `Session` object. Documentation on the `Session` object is sparse, but sufficient to be confident that the database is specified as part of a `connectionString` parameter. If that is true, what is the format of this string?

Information from [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) suggests a connection string including `database=mychosendb` should be equivalent to the SQL `USE mychosendb` command. So far I cannot see a way to make either of the two obvious approaches work:

- my existing connection string in the form `host=localhost;user=mylogin;password=mypassword` works fine, but does not specify a database; when I add variations on `database=mychosendb` to the string, it seems to be ignored.
- trying to execute an SQL `USE` command informs me that this is not a command supported by this interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. It's the blindingly-obvious-once-you-know-but-not-before case of needing to use the abbreviated `db=mychosendb` instead of any longer form `database=mychosendb` or `Database=mychosendb` - neither of the latter work, at least not for me.

Whether or not this is the preferred method, I don't know. But I know it works.